# SUDO, PK EXEC, ETC. NOT PRESENT ON MAC

Tags: macos, path, sudo, path-finding, bin

Currently I’m on my 2015 Macbook Pro with an Aura Pro X2 1TB internal drive (not sure if that changes the mounting).

I’m very new to terminal and have been looking everywhere for an explanation on why my **SUDO / PKEXEC / ETC.** are not working and/or there’s no directory.

I’ve been reading around and it seems the **closest problem is my PATH is going to the wrong spot** possibly, but I’m not sure how it happened so I can’t fix it.

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

```
> ls -l /etc/sudoers
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root wheel 1563 Mar 13 2020 /etc/sudoers
```

All the files that are said to not have malfunctioned like: *bash_profile*, etc. are not found on my computer. At least I don’t think.

If anyone could help me out that would be a blessing.

Comment: macOS has `sudo` (as /usr/bin/sudo), but not `pkexec`.

Answer (score 1):

Commands are case-sensitive. Most commands (if not all) are in lowercase, meaning it's `sudo` and not `SUDO`.